# Complete the character table of group of order $21$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

You are given the incomplete character table of a group $G$ with order $21$ which has $5$ conjugacy classes, $C_1,\dots,C_5$, which have sizes $1,7,7,3,3$.

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 & C_5 \\ \hline
 &  & & & & \\ \hline
 &  &  && &  \\ \hline
\chi_2 & 1 & \zeta_3 & \zeta_3^2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
 &  &  & & &  \\ \hline
\chi_4 & 3 & 0 & 0 & \zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4 & \zeta_7^{-1}+\zeta_7^{-2}+\zeta_7^{-4} \\ \hline 
\end{array}
$$

Complete the character table.

Im guessing that $\chi_0$ has to be the trivial representation so we get that

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 & C_5 \\ \hline
 \chi_0 & 1 &1 & 1& 1&1 \\ \hline
 & 1 &  && &  \\ \hline
\chi_2 & 1 & \zeta_3 & \zeta_3^2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
 & 3 &  & & &  \\ \hline
\chi_4 & 3 & 0 & 0 & \zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4 & \zeta_7^{-1}+\zeta_7^{-2}+\zeta_7^{-4} \\ \hline 
\end{array}
$$

and as $21=1+1+1+9+9$.

Im sure you have to obtain something from the fact we have 3rd and 7th roots of unity which correspond to the sizes of the conjugacy classes but I cannot see what I am meant to glimmer from this.

Hints only please.

Comment: $21=1+1+1+9+9$..

Comment: but $21=1+1+9+4+4+1+1$?

Comment: why does that matter?? do you know how many irreducible representations you should have if you know no of conjugacy classes??

Comment: possibly havent got there yet in my course

Comment: i doubt that.... i guess you should have done that otherwise there is no way you can go through this... (i believe)...

Comment: ah its next lecture. Ill edit the question now

Comment: so, i guess you should wait till next lecture.... then you can see why $21=1+1+1+9+9$ makes sense and not $21=1+1+9+4+4+1+1$

Comment: there is some typo.. you have written 1 dimensional representations 4 times.. it should be only 3

Comment: Hint: The inverse of a linear character is also a linear character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remaining two characters are algebraic conjugates of $\chi_2$ and $\chi_4$. You get them by replacing $\zeta_3$ by $\zeta_3^2$, and $\zeta_7$ by $\zeta_7^3$, respectively.